# Problema con PromptBuilder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Eh creado este codigo con la finalidad de poder copiar todo lo que hable en un cuadro de texto, pero quiero que se pueda hacer fuera del cuadro de texto.

Aqui el codigo que implemente
Código:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace Test
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        
    PromptBuilder dictado = new PromptBuilder();
    SpeechSynthesizer habla = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    SpeechRecognitionEngine escucha = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    string speech;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ActivarEscucha();
    }


    private void ActivarEscucha()
    {
        escucha.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        escucha.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
        escucha.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        escucha.SpeechRecognized += Escucha_SpeechRecognized;
        habla.SpeakAsync("Esperando Dictado");
    }

    private void Escucha_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        speech = e.Result.Text;
// dictado.AppendText(speech);        
    textbox.AppendText(speech); <-- si yo coloco esta linea, me escribe lo que hable en el textbox, yo necesito es que lo escriba fuera del textbox

    }
}
```

}

Espero puedan ayudarme a solventar este problema , gracias.

Comment: cuando dices fuera del textbox, dónde específicamente? en un messagebox? en otro control (cuál)? en otra ventana?

Comment: me refiero y pongo como ejemplo , este cuadro de texto donde estoy escribiendo actualmente mi respuesta, me explico mejor , en caso de querer dictar en word o bloc de notas o la barra de direcciones del explorador, poder hacerlo dictando al microfono.

Comment: Lo que estás tratando de hacer es una característica del sistema operativo que ya existe ([dictado](https://www.howtogeek.com/177539/how-to-get-started-with-speech-recognition-on-windows-7-or-8/)), y que desde código va a ser muy difícil replicar. En general las aplicaciones debieran modificar sus propios controles y no los de otras apps.

Comment: exacto, dictado, y funciona si lo aplico a un txtbox mas no tengo idea de como aplicarlo fuera de un txtbox y es mi duda, sabes que se debe hacer?

Comment: En el caso de que el "fuera del textbox" sea un control dentro de la misma app, tienes que obtener una referencia al control que quieres modificar y ejecutar la acción (modificar el contenido del campo de texto, presionar el botón, etc...).

Comment: y no existe algun metodo o forma, que escriba fuera del txtbox de la app osea , como por ejemplo en este cuadro de texto donde escribo esta respuesta, asi como lo hace el de windows o alguna forma de llamar el dictado de windows en c# , por wpf?